# Mudar cor do item Listview no xamarin de acordo com os dados do banco

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Preciso mudar a cor do item da listview de acordo com o dados quem vem do banco, tenho um campo visitado que esta recebendo um "*" gostaria de mudar a cor da pessoa que já foi visitada.

Estou trazendo a busca desta maneira:

```
  players = new ArrayList();
        var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), abrir.Nome_banco);
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(), path);
        sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(path, null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite);

        sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenOrCreateDatabase(path, null);

        Android.Database.ICursor sqldb_cursor = null;
        sqldb_query = "SELECT visitado,nome FROM pessoa where grupo_id ='"+grupo_id+"'order by nome asc";
        sqldb_cursor = sqldb.RawQuery(sqldb_query, null);
        if (!(sqldb_cursor != null))
        {


        }

        if (sqldb_cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                //formando aqui

                players.Add(sqldb_cursor.GetString(0) + sqldb_cursor.GetString(1));

            } while (sqldb_cursor.MoveToNext());

        }
```

Código do adapter:
 `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, players);
            lv.Adapter = adapter;`

Comment: A mudança de cor deve ser feita no adapter.

Comment: Isso, teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Coloque o código do adapter na pergunta.

Comment: ramaral coloquei o código do adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você deverá customizar o Adapter e fazer algo como isso no GetView:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.From(this.context).Inflate('Your layout axml', parent, false);
    }

    convertView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);

    return convertView;
}
```

Fonte: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335555/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-last-item-in-listview)

Tem também essa forma onde você não precisa customizar o adapter e sim sobrepor o método:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations()) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

{
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    String currentLocation = RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Current_Location);
    int textColor = textView.getText().toString().equals(currentLocation) ? R.color.holo_blue : R.color.text_color_btn_holo_dark;
    textView.setTextColor(RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getColor(textColor));

    return textView;
}

});
```

Fonte: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Comment: Pelo adapter não entendi como que passo os valores e faço a comparação. Saberia me dizer ?

Comment: Dentro do adapter você já tem o getItem() , crie uma regra baseado nele (ex. se for um campo de valor e for negativo a cor deve ser vemelha).

Comment: Tem algum exemplo, consigo verificar o valor que esta dentro do adapter com getItem? Por que estou buscando duas colunas, mas elas se concatena.

Comment: Isso depende de como está implementado o getItem (no caso de ser um custom adapter). Pesquise por Custom Adapter  Android, deverá encontrar vários casos de adapters customizados que poderão esclarecer melhor o funcionamento.